# using "touch" to create directories?

Tags: linux, bash

1) in the "A" directory:

```
find . -type f > a.txt
```

2) in the "B" directory:

```
cat a.txt | while read FILENAMES; do touch "$FILENAMES"; done
```

3) Result: the 2) "creates the files" [i mean only with the same filename, but with 0 Byte size] ok. But if there are subdirs in the "A" directory, then the 2) can't create the files in the subdir, because there are no directories in it.

Question: is there a way, that `touch` can create directories?

Comment: Cross-post: http://superuser.com/questions/234185/using-touch-to-create-directories

Comment: @Peter: 10 questions, 8 with answers. zero accepted answers and zero upvotes on both StackOverflow and SuperUser. And now a cross-post. Sigh...

Comment: Another [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/223267/using-touch-to-create-directories). Please don't do that.

Comment: Super User was the right place to ask this.  Cross posting is allowed if a question fits the criteria for more than one site, but in this case it's much better suited for SU.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `find` outputs one file per line:

```
cat a.txt | while read file; do
    if [[ "$file" = */* ]]; then
        mkdir -p "${file%/*}";
    fi;

    touch "$file";
done
```

EDIT:

This would be slightly more efficient if the directories where created in a separate step:

```
cat a.txt | grep / | sed 's|/[^/]*$||' | sort -u | xargs -d $'\n' mkdir -p

cat a.txt | while read file; do
    touch "$file";
done
```

And, no, `touch` cannot create directories on its own.

Answer (score -1):

No. Why not just use mkdir instead of touch for directories?

Comment: It would be useful to create needed directories, then create the file. will be easier than running 2 commands to fulfill the same purpose. It's linux and I expect it to be smart ;)