# Command line interface for editor

Tags: shell, command-line-interface

There's a lot of possibilities on how to create a **CLI** for an app, but I don't want to overcomplicate it.

I want to create a script to which I can pass an argument with file or directory and this script will be able to determine whether this file/directory exists and if so it'll open an app in it or if it doesn't it'll create it and then open and app.

It's easy to check for existance of *the location* eg.

```
if [[ -d $PASSED ]]; then
    echo "$PASSED is a directory"
elif [[ -f $PASSED ]]; then
    echo "$PASSED is a file"
else
    echo "$PASSED is not valid"
    exit 1
fi
```

but I have no idea how to solve the distinction between handling non existent thing eg. I can have a file or a directory, so `./coder no_such_file.txt` should create a file in current directory, but I can as well call it like `./coder directory/` and how to determine it? Is it possible to determine it *automatically* or do I have to parse it and check for `/`?

Comment: does it make a difference in `./coder` if it is given a file or a directory? I can't see the point. If you want to create either a file or directory (that obviously does not exist then) you have to give the user a way to make a distinction between them, either by forcing him to append / for a directory or by a flag...and you then have to handle it appropriately

Comment: This whole script is supposed to work with text editor, so user may want to open a text editor in a directory which doesn't exist, yet. Also it makes sense to allow user to create a file, right? So, I'll have to check for `/` anyways to determine if it's a directory.

Comment: I think it makes far more sense to create a file than a directory (unless the file would be in a not-yet-existing directory), but users may vary...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using "touch" to create directories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711465/using-touch-to-create-directories)

Comment: See *Dan Rosenstark's* answer to [using “touch” to create directories?](http://superuser.com/a/567919/582419), for a *ruby* script `touchMakingDirs` that fits the bill.